# How are the constructor points awarded in F1?

Tags: formula-1

Here is the Constructors' Championship as it stands after the 2022 Hungarian Grand Prix:

[image: Budapest 2022 F1]

What I understand is that the constructor points are awarded based on the drivers' race positions, plus with fastest lap point. For example, at the Bahrain Grand Prix, Ferrari got 44 points: 25 from Leclerc, 18 from Sainz, plus 1 point for fastest lap.

However, if you look at the Austrian Grand Prix, Ferrari got 38 points while Sainz did not finish the race. **Where did the other 13 points come from?**

Answer (score 3):

Austria is one of three "[sprint weekends](https://www.formula1.com/en/latest/article.formula-1-to-hold-three-sprint-events-in-2022-with-more-points-on-offer.4UXmrMDm6We04ZFlW0Ieo9.html)" on the 2022 calendar (along with Italy and Brazil), that schedules a mini race on Saturday to set the Sunday GP grid.  This sprint race also awards championship points for the first 8 finishers.

[F1 Sprint Results Austria 2022](https://www.formula1.com/en/results.html/2022/races/1115/austria/sprint-results.html) shows that the Ferrari cars finished 2 and 3 in the sprint (behind Verstappen) with Leclerc getting 7 points and Sainz getting 6.

Note Red Bull's 58 points in Italy on your graphic.  That's more than the normal maximum of 44 possible for a traditional race weekend.